# Curious matrix, how can I easiest explain it's behaviour?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I just found this matrix

$${\bf M} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0.5\\-8&-3\end{array}\right]$$

I have not figured out if my factorization makes sense:

$${\bf M} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\-8&1\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&\frac{1}{2}\\0&1\end{array}\right]$$

The curious behaviour I want to explain is:

$$({{\bf M}^k})_{11} = (-1)^{k-1}(2k-1)$$

Does the factorization help in explaining the behavior or would we do better trying something else?

[image]
Plot over value of element as function of exponent.

Comment: Your formula suggests that its Jordan form is $$J=\pmatrix{-1&1\\0&-1}. $$ Can you find $A$ with $M=A^{-1}JA$?

Comment: The given matrices don't commute. You need to further decompose, so that you can split the powers across simpler matrices.

Comment: I'd do it the way @LordSharktheUnknown suggests. But I have an uneasy feeling I've seen stuff on sequences of vectors got by operating with alternating upper/lower $2\times 2$ unitriangular matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @LordSharktheUnknown 's comment. Just use Jordan-decomposition. Observe
\begin{align}
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{8}\\
1  & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-8  & -2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
M^k = \begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{8}\\
1  & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}^k
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-8  & -2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{8}\\
1  & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
(-1)^k & (-1)^{k-1}k\\
0 & (-1)^k
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-8  & -2
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
I will leave it to you to multiply everything.

Comment: Yes, wonderful explanation! And also falls out directly from the method that the -2 in lower right of rightmost matrix is the $\Delta$, we can alter it to -3 and then construct increments of $\pm 3$ and so on.